# Writing to .bin binary file

Tags: c#, file, file-io, binary

I am trying to write integer numbers to binary file, but it keeps giving weird characters in the binary file. For example, I try to write 2000, but in the file i will get something strange. How do I fix it? Couldn't find the solution anywhere.

I use the following code:

```
 //create the file
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("iram.bin", FileMode.Create);
        // Create the writer for data.
        BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs);

w.Write((int) 2000);

w.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Comment: `FileStream` and `BinaryWriter` both implement the `IDisposable` interface. Wrap their usage in a `using` block and forgo the explicit `.Close()`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not reading the data back properly.

You will need to read the data back using a BinaryReader like so...

```
    using (FileStream fs2 = new FileStream("iram.bin", FileMode.Open))
    {
        using(BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(fs2))
        {
            var integerValue = r.ReadInt32();
        }
    }
```

Unless of course you actually want to write text to the file in which case you probably don't want a BinaryWriter to write the data out.

If you actually want to write out text data you could do so like this...  (Be sure to set your encoding to what you need)

```
    using (var tw = new StreamWriter("iram.txt", true, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        tw.WriteLine(2000);
    }
```

Edit: As Jesse mentioned you normally want to wrap disposable objects in using blocks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting unexpected chars in the file is because what you're writing to the file is not meant to be interpreted as a sequence of chars in the first place

When you open it in notepad or another text editor, It will just take what's there, guess the encoding(or use a default), and show you whatever chars the data would encode if it were encoding chars.  It's not intended to be human readable.

---

A human readable text file that has the character sequence `2000` actually has an encoding of the character `2`, followed by the encoding of `0` 3 times.

in Unicode it's `U+0032U+0030U+0030U+0030`

Comment: Umm, no.  The OP is casting the 2000 to an int, so it's 0x7D0, or in binary, probably 4 bytes 0000 0111 1101 0000.  Not Unicode

Comment: @DanPichelman you misunderstood that part.  I was trying to illustrate what the encoding might be in a file that would display `"2000"` if he opened it in a text editor

Comment: @DanPichelman I did it to illustrate the difference between a binary file and a readable file

Comment: @DanPichelman: I do believe it'll be written little-endian: 00, D0, 07, 00.