# How to retrieve integer value from binary file in C#

Tags: c#

I am writing the integer value in binary file as follows:-

```
int val =10;

FileStream fs = new FileStream("BinaryFile.bin", FileMode.Create);
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs, Encoding.Unicode);

bw.Write(val);

//Reading value from binary as:-

FileStream fs = new FileStream("BinaryFile.bin", FileMode.Open);
  BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs, Encoding.Unicode);

int x = br.ReadInt32();
```

Value retrieved is: 1.092616E + 09

I am getting this value instead of '10'

Is there any other method to retrieve the int value?

Comment: Works fine for me. How are you displaying `x`?

Comment: I am just displaying x in message box.

Comment: What happens when you debug the code and step over the `ReadInt32` line.. does `x` hold `10`?

Comment: 1) Try Encoding.UTF8 instead. 2) Set the offset to 0 explicitly.

Comment: No x holds the same value which it displays..@Itachi I am supposed to use Encode.Unicode only . Is there any other any other way which can be used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by making change in BinaryWriter constructor

as

```
 FileStream fs = new FileStream("iram.bin", FileMode.Create);
        // Create the writer for data.
        BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs);

w.Write((int) 2000);

w.Close();
fs.Close();
```

and read using

```
using (FileStream fs2 = new FileStream("iram.bin", FileMode.Open))
    {
        using(BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(fs2))
        {
            var integerValue = r.ReadInt32();
        }
    }
```

More detail [Writing to .bin binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552787/c-sharp-writing-to-bin-binary-file)